# Find the value for the constant $k$ which will make this limit exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the value for the constant $k$ such that

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(4^{kx}+6)}{(4^{2x}+4)}$$

exists.

Comment: Can you guess??

Comment: Hint: What happens when $k > 2$?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to math.SE! This forum is full of free-spirited people who are happy to respond to questions. You have techincally written a question, but lots of potential answerers are going to go help another poster who frames his/her question nicely by including partial work and thoughts, and who phrased their question less like a command. You might consider making such changes to improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
Divide all terms in numerator and denominator by $4^{2x}:$
$$L= \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{4^{kx}+6}{4^{2x}+4}= \lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} \frac{4^{(k-2)x}+\dfrac{6}{4^{2x}}}{1+\dfrac{4}{4^{2x}}}$$
Since $\dfrac{6}{4^{2x}}\underset{x\to{+\infty}}{\to} 0$ and $\dfrac{4}{4^{2x}}\underset{x\to{+\infty}}{\to} 0$ then depending on value of $k$ we have following possibilities:

1. $k>2 \Rightarrow {4^{(k-2)x} \underset{x\to{+\infty}}{\to} {+\infty}},$ therefore, $L=+\infty$;
2. $k=2 \Rightarrow L=1 $;
3. $k<2 \Rightarrow L=0 $.

Comment: so would this leave me with 1^(k-2)? Its been a while since Ive had to divide exponents which leaves me very rusty

Comment: oh so k would have to be equal to or less than 2 in order for the limit to exist?

Comment: Yes, limit exist for $k\leqslant{2}.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  when $x$ gets large, the $6$ is negligible compared with $4^{kx}$.  You can make this explicit by dividing through by $4^{kx}$

Comment: so would that leave me with 1/1^(2-k) or did I do that wrong?

Comment: @user57172: you are right, you can ignore the $+4$ as well.  No, it should be $\frac 1{4^{(2-k)x}}$.  Now can you find what happens for various values of $k$ as $x$ gets large?

Comment: wouldnt the limit go towards infinity for any number of k though, other than 2 itself?

Comment: @user57172:  No, if $k=1$, for example, it will decrease to zero.

Comment: oh ok I see that now!